# table between rows of another table

Tags: html, xslt

I am trying to put a table between rows of another table .

But after I put a table after several rows , the original rows are lost their format .

Any idea how to fix this issue .
My knowledge of xslt is little bit limited .

```
<table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#006699">
            <th ALIGN="LEFT">PCB Barcode</th>
            <th ALIGN="LEFT">Date and Time</th>
            <th ALIGN="LEFT">ProductPWI</th>
            <th ALIGN="LEFT">Conveyor Speed</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="GeneralReflowProcessReport/Results/GeneralReflowProcessReportEntry/PcbInfo/PcbInfoEntries/PcbInfoEntry">
            <tr>
                <td style='padding:2px 100px 2px 2px'><xsl:value-of select="PcbBarcode"/></td>
                <td style='padding:2px 20px 2px 2px'><xsl:value-of select="ReflowTime"/></td>
                <td style='padding:2px 20px 2px 2px'><xsl:value-of select="ProductPWI"/></td>
                <td style='padding:2px 20px 2px 2px'><xsl:value-of select="ConveyorSpeed"/></td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:if test="PcbStatistics/PcbStatisticsEntries">
                <br/>
                    <table border="1" >

                        <tr bgcolor="#006699">
                            <th ALIGN="LEFT">Statistics Limits:</th>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style='padding:2px 100px 2px 2px'><xsl:value-of select="PcbStatistics/PcbStatisticsEntries/PcbStatisticsEntry/StatisticsName"/></td>

                        </tr>
                </table>
                <br/>
            </xsl:if>


        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
```

[image]

Comment: First decide what HTML you need to generate, and check that it works in the browser. Then start thinking about how to write the XSLT code to generate this HTML. Trying to do both at the same time, especially when you are inexperienced in both HTML and XSLT, is a recipe for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the table inside a CELL in your current table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Outer table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Inner table</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Because what he is trying to do is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

HTML syntax does not allow anything between the rows of a table, except rows of the same table. You can however insert a single-cell row of that table and put a table inside that cell; in that case you should use a `colspan` attribute that makes that cell occupy the full width of the (outer) table, in this case `<td colspan=4>`.

Alternatively, you can insert a row or rows that contain the desired data so that they are syntactically normal rows of the table, even if their content is different. Note that using CSS you can set borders, backgrounds, etc., for the cells of a row different from the rest of the table. However, the special rows must still fit into the structure of the table. For example, if a row is to contain just two cells and the table has four columns, then you need to specify, with `colspan` attributes, how the two cells are placed into the grid of the table (e.g., `<tr><td>...</td><td colspan=3>...</td></tr>` would place the first cell in the first column and make the second cell span the rest of the columns, in your case).

Answer (score 0):

do something with CSS with DIV

```
<div id="outer">
<div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```